# how to add fields to contact us page for product tab step by step

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90, nopcommerce-3.80, nopcommerce-themes

Hi there how do you add fields to the **contact us** page for nop commerce step by step im new to nop commerce I tried to add a field in **ProductContactUs.cshtml** but i got a error

**Plugins/SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.NopQuickTabs/Views/ProductTab/_ProductContactUs.cshtml**

the field i added was **postaladdress** like so

```
                     <div class="inputs">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostalAddress)
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PostalAddress, new { @class = 
                        "postaladdress", placeholder = T("ContactUs.PostalAddress.Hint") })
                        @Html.RequiredHint()
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostalAddress)
                        </div>
```

Where else should I add the field. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add PostalAddress to the ContactUsModel model. The location of the viewmodel at Nop.Web==>Models==>Common. It will get read of your application from initial error but it will not reflect the change to the functionality of the plugin.

Comment: Hi sina_Islam can you be more specific where to find models is it in views plugins where

Comment: im looking for ContactUsModel but i dont find it in my files

Comment: if go to the Nop.Web==>Plugins==>SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.NopQuickTabs==>Views==>ProductTab==>_ProductContactUs.cshtml at the top of the partialview you will see `@using Nop.Web.Models.Common;
@model ContactUsModel` so the partial view strongly tied to the  ContactUsModel which is situated at Presentation==>Nop.Web==>Models==>Common==>ContactUsModel.cs(you can see that only if you work with nopcommerce source code).